# Why won't Sonic & Knuckles collection work on my windows 10 computer?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, windows-10, sonic-3-and-knuckles

It says "This app can't run on your pc. To find a version for your pc, check with the software publisher." and no compatibility options will work. I'm using a 64 bit win10 laptop.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it will be able to run on Windows 10. So much has changed since that game's release so it probably just isn't compatible.

Comment: I was able to get this working on Win7 about a year ago. I'll do some testing later on today to see if I can get it working on my Win10 machine.

Comment: @nukeforum - Any luck?

Comment: @Robotnik I seem to have misplaced my copy of the game while moving recently. I'll keep digging for it, but I have no idea where it is.

Comment: @nukeforum - No worries, just checking :)

Comment: I've heard that there are several Mega Drive / Genesis emulators which work very well on Windows 10. Too bad that most ways to get the ROMs are illegal.

Comment: Steam's got [Sonic 3 & Knuckles](http://store.steampowered.com/app/71162/). Just have in mind that the Sonic and Knuckles Collection for PC [uses a unique soundtrack for the games](http://info.sonicretro.org/Sonic_%26_Knuckles_Collection#Differences_from_console_version). Plus, you can play Sonic 3 or Sonic & Knuckles separated on Sonic & Knuckles Collection.

Comment: @DBB What is "it"? The game executable? The installation  executable? Autorun? An emulator? Are you talking about Sonic 3 & Knuckles in particular, or is there a wrapper for the collection you're trying to open?

Answer (score 2):

Was able to install it by doing the following steps:

1. Insert the CD
2. Right click on your CD Drive and select "Open"
3. Open folder INSTALL
4. Double click SETUP.EXE
5. Install and run the game normally

[image: Sonic 3 & Knuckles running on Windows 10 64-bit]

I had no need to install DirectX 3 as prompted by the game setup since my DirectX version is far more superior (you won't be needing DirectX 3 as well as Windows 10 probably have a superior version pre-installed).

Answer (score 2):

**It CAN work depending on a few things.**

One thing to note is that because my laptop doesn't have a CD Drive, I had to create a .iso file from my existing disc (using an older Windows XP Laptop), which I sent to my laptop.
Then, I ran the .iso file, which created a new drive on File Explorer, appearing as if I had inserted the disc (appeared as `DVD Drive D: SONIC3K`). Ran `INSTALL.EXE`, installed fine, works fine.

Comment: So you're saying to use a disc (be it virtually or physically)? It's a shame we don't know what file the OP was running.